# Ajax jQuery getting Error: [object Error]

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i try to send a parameter to my Webservice to get the Data. But iam getting always an Error: [object Error]

[Error-Snapshot](http://i47.tinypic.com/2z55fte.png)

What does that Error means?

The Webservice is working so far. If i Invoke the Webmethod in the Browser i get all the data.

What iam doing wrong. I have tried many things, but nothing helped.. Hope you can help me

My Query:

```
    function loadDate() {

        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        PanelID = document.getElementById('PanelID').value;
        alert(PanelID);


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://nexxt-entwicklung.de/Web/Service1.asmx/getDatetime",
            data: "{ 'PanelID': '" + PanelID + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("Success: " + msg.d);

            },
            error: function(msg) {
                alert("Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText);

            }
        });   
    }
```

My Webservice:

```
 [ScriptService]
public class Helper
{
    public class VERANSTALTUNGEN
    {
    public string Von { get; set; }
    public string Bis { get; set; }
    public string Thema { get; set; }
    public string PanelIDs { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<VERANSTALTUNGEN> getDatetime(string PanelID)
        {

            List<VERANSTALTUNGEN> Besprechungen = new List<VERANSTALTUNGEN>();

            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT DISTINCT r.PanelID AS PANEL_ID, rr.Von AS DATEVON, rr.Bis AS DATEBIS, b.THEMA AS BESPRECHUNGSTHEMA FROM RAUM r right join RESERVIERUNGRAUM rr ON r.ID = rr.Raum_ID right join BUCHUNG b ON rr.BUCHUNG_ID = b.ID where r.PANELID = @ID ORDER BY rr.VON");

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT_LH;Integrated Security=true;"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char);
                cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = PanelID;
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        if (rdr["DATEVON"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["DATEBIS"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            Besprechungen.Add(new VERANSTALTUNGEN()
                            {
                                Von = rdr["DATEVON"].ToString(),
                                Bis = rdr["DATEBIS"].ToString(),
                                Thema = rdr["BESPRECHUNGSTHEMA"].ToString(),
                                PanelIDs = rdr["PANEL_ID"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Besprechungen;
     }
}
```

Webservice Method

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public List<Helper.VERANSTALTUNGEN> getDatetime(string PanelID)
        {
            return Helper.getDatetime(PanelID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now i opened the url with STRG+Mouse click in visual studio. I get an Http 500 error. But in the browser the url works? Could that be the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

It means that `msg.statusText` is an object that is an instance of `Error`.

Use `console.log` instead of `alert` to see what the object contains in a console in Chrome/Firebug, or loop through the object and alert each key/value.

Comment: i tried with firebug now, but it only shows failed : 0 : error

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the problem itself, while using dataType json:

you shouldn't do:

```
data: "{ 'PanelID': '" + PanelID + "' }",
```

but rather something like

```
data: { 'PanelID': PanelID },
```

cause otherwise instead of posting some object you're sending string

do always make sure you read the specs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: then probably you should read David's hint and try to verify what is the Error even saying. You could also debug the c# code to check what is happening there - whether the parameters you're passing are correctly mapped. The error could be caused not only by the JS side, by also by the Webservice throwing exception.

Comment: i added a comment to my question, can you look at it please

Comment: you could install firebug. go to tab script - enable it - reload the page - find there your script `alert("Failed: ...` add there a breakpoint (clicking on the left from the line numbers) - trigger the event. Then after the breakpoint is hit, go to console and inspect the msg element (just type msg in console and browse the result). Then you can probably see the internal error message

Comment: if you searched for the problem on stack you could actually find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463028/jquery-ajax-call-return-value which states that while using .net webservices u should be looking at `msg.d`.